# jQuery, loop over elements with only partial name or id known

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with multiple inputs generated by javascript.  The names and IDs are generated by javascript.

I need to loop over the elements to set their values, but the names and IDs of each element include their own unique integer that I don't know to easily get access to.

An example element name is:

```
test[result_fields_attributes][1468515178049][name]
```

An example element id is:

```
test_result_fields_attributes_1468515178049_name
```

Does anyone know a way to loop over multiple elements like those when I don't know what that long integer is for each element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can access like

```
 $("input[id^='test_result_fields_attributes']").each(function(){
   //you code use $(this)
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Attribute Starts With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
$('[name^="test[result_fields_attributes]"]');
```

Although a better method entirely would be to put a common class on all the elements you require and select them by that instead.

Comment: like the idea of coding a common class... thanks for the heads'up

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [startswith](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector  like

```
  $('[id^=test_result_fields_attributes]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`Attribute Starts With Selector [name^=”value”]`**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('[id^="test_result_fields_attributes_"]')
```